# Delphi , MySQL , VarBinary , is this the "right" way?

Tags: mysql, delphi, varbinary

I have a working AES Encryption and Decryption algorithm . Which I now can save to inifile with WriteBinaryStream and ReadBinaryStream. So it was only natural that I tried to to the same in MySQL . At first I tried varchar which did not work , so I switched to varbinary . This is how I do it :

**Encrypt and save to MySQL varbinary field .**

```
UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pPassword').Value:=TEncoding.ANSI.GetBytes(aes_encrypt(Edit2.Text));
```

**Decrypt and display in Edit.Text**

```
Edit2.Text:=aes_decrypt(TStringStream.Create(TEncoding.ANSI.GetString(UserMain.UserQueryPassword.AsBytes)));
```

Well it works, it looks simple , which means I think it is okay :) I tried it for a while now , I can always decode the password no matter the length .

Am I doing this "right" or is here something dangerous present ?

Comment: One tip, do not implement decoding of an encrypted password in your application. It is unsecure. Better is to create a one way hash for each user password with a variable salt. When the time comes to check the password you create a hash from the user input, use orginal Salt and compare hashes, if they are the same the password is correct. This method will prevent (or at least slow down) hackers that stole your database to get the original passwords and misuse them...

Comment: @whosrdaddy, exactly; what's more, a business layer can resolve this. Having one, you prevent fetching pure text (or easily decryptable) passwords on the client side.